# Is it advisable to run Jenkins on Macmini

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, data-transfer

Have a 10 node Jenkins setup which is currently distributed across AWS and a Macmini service provider.

- Jenkins Master in AWS
- 8 Macmini nodes in a data center (Macmini service provider)

This is costing us a lot of data transfer charges. One option I was thinking was to move the Jenkins master to one of the MacMini nodes. Is hosting Jenkins on Macmini a good reliable option ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with running Jenkins on a Mac. But I'm curious about your data transfer charges. Jenkins itself doesn't send a whole lot of data *to* agents. Definitely not enough to cause concern over data transfer charges (when you are already paying for hosting 8 mac minis). What else is your pipeline pulling from AWS? Any mac virtualization images?

Comment: I will have to check that. @Iterokun.